# Wifi: not configured

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I was removing a wifi network and after removing it, my wifi icon is blank, showing a cross over it, while i hover over it which says **Not Configured**, I googled the problem but didn't find any solution to the problem, I tried reinstalling mavericks, while everything (user, setting and everything remain same) the problem remain same too. What can be the problem? How can I fix it? 
[image: wifi info]  and [image: network info]

Comment: Go to about my mac => more info => system report => Network => WiFi and post a print screen

Comment: @Thomas I edited the question and posted a screenshot, not on PC but from mobile

Comment: Thanks, could you also provide one with about my mac => more info => system report => Network ?

Comment: @Thomas  I updated it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than removing a Wi-Fi network, it appears you've removed the Wi-Fi service. In OS X prior to 10.10, this means the AirPort shows Not Configured.

To allow configuration of AirPort, you need to add the Wi-Fi service back to the list of services:

1. Go to System Preferences → Network and click the **+** button to add a service.
2. Select Wi-Fi as the Interface and provide a service name.

   [image]

This will allow configuration through the menu bar item.

Comment: @Georhe Garside it worked, thanks mate. Should I delete the screenshots from question as it MAC address?

Comment: @Nofel No problem! You can if you want; it'll still be in the question's revision history though. Flag for a moderator if you want an older revision deleting.

Comment: @grgarside It works well for macOS Sierra! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As even after installation, your hardware is not functioning, then it certainly HS. Do an [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) in advance mode (could take time)